# Get users watching facebook live video?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there an endpoint for getting the current users watching a facebook live video? Looking at the reference at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/, I can get the total number of users currently watching, but there doesn't appear to be an edge for retrieving those users... is this even possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. And even if it was, what would you even want to do with that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a feature supported by the Graph API at the moment. There are edges for comments, likes, and reactions, so you could get a list of some of the users who have watched with those edges, but there is no way to list all viewers.

Comment: Bummer. Is there any way to request features?

Comment: You can send feedback here: [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/268228883256323). BTW, if I answered your question you should consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer :)